# read.Lines all webpages after a URL

Tags: r, web-crawler, readline

In order to do some textual analysis in R, I would like to download several webpages that have a very similar design. I have tried it with several pages and this code indeed only keeps the lines I am interested in.

```
thepage= readLines("http://example/xwfw_665399/s2510_665401/t1480900.shtml")
thepage2 = readLines("http://example/xwfw_665399/s2510_665401/2535_665405/t851768.shtml")


mypattern1 = '<P style=\\"FONT.*\\">'

datalines1 = grep(mypattern1,thepage[1:length(thepage)],value=TRUE)
datalines2 = grep(mypattern1,thepage2[1:length(thepage)],value=TRUE)


mypattern2 = '<STRONG>'

mypattern3 = '</STRONG>'

mypattern4 = '</P>'


page1=gsub(mypattern1,"",datalines1)
page1=gsub(mypattern2,"", page1)
page1=gsub(mypattern3,"",page1)
page1=gsub(mypattern4,"",page1)

page2=gsub(mypattern1,"",datalines2)
page2=gsub(mypattern2,"", page2)
page2=gsub(mypattern3,"",page2)
page2=gsub(mypattern4,"",page2)
```

As you might see, the URLS are very similar, ending with s2510_665401/ 
Now, I wonder, is there a way to automatically retrieve all possible files after s2510_665401/ and have my code run over them? Despite some googleing, I haven't been able to find anything. Would it require to write a function? If so, would someone please point me in the right direction? 
Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you could either share the real URL, or another URL with a similar structure so we can reproduce the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a final working answer, I very rarely do web scraping so not sure how well this generalizes to other webpages, but it may help you in the right direction. Consider [this page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/). We can write a function that extracts all `.html` elements, which we can then again crawl with the same function to get their references.

So in the code below, `unique(refs_1)` contains all `.html` pages that are one level deep, and `unique(refs_2)` contains all `.html` pages that are two levels deep.

You would still need a wrapper to either stop after a certain number of iterations, maybe prevent recrawling of already visited pages (`setdiff(refs_2,refs_1)?`), etc.

when you have all the URLs to scrape (in this case `unique(c(refs_1,refs_2))`, you should wrap your own read script in a function, and call `lapply(x,f)`, where x is the list/array of URLs, and `f` is your function.`

Anyway, hope this helps!

```
library(qdapRegex)

get_refs_on_page <- function(page){
  refs = lapply( tryCatch({readLines(page)}, error=function(cond){return(NA)},warning=function(cond){return(NA)})
                 , function(x) {y=rm_between(x  , "href=\"", "\"", extract=TRUE)[[1]]})
  refs=unlist(refs)
  refs = refs[!is.na(refs)]
  return(refs)
}

thepage = 'https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/'
refs_1 = get_refs_on_page(thepage)
refs_2 = unlist(lapply(paste0(thepage,refs_1),get_refs_on_page))
```

Example output:

```
 > unique(c(refs_1,refs_2))
  [1] "?C=N;O=D"                              "?C=M;O=A"                              "?C=S;O=A"                             
  [4] "?C=D;O=A"                              "/R-manual/R-devel/library/"            "DESCRIPTION"                          
  [7] "doc/"                                  "html/"                                 "?C=N;O=A"                             
 [10] "?C=M;O=D"                              "?C=S;O=D"                              "?C=D;O=D"                             
 [13] "/doc/html/R.css"                       "/doc/html/index.html"                  "../../../library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf"
 [16] "../../../library/utils/doc/Sweave.Rnw" "../../../library/utils/doc/Sweave.R"   "Sweave.Rnw.~r55105~"
```

Comment: Thanks! I could only reproduce your example when I started with page = https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/ and replaced (thepage) with (page)? In my example, http://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/xwfw_665399/s2510_665401/, refs_1 remained empty . I don't need to go down another level, at least something!

Comment: Hi @SCW, refs_1 should not remain empty in your case I think, since it should probably go to the folder `2535_665405` to find `2535_665405/t851768.shtml`? I updated my answer, maybe this works better for you.